# rails ajax dynamically select where to render partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a loop statement in my html template that generates a number of divs and buttons with with unique ids. The resulting html is similar to below...

```
// show.html.erb
<button id="button-town-data1"><%= link_to 'Load Details', town_path(current_user.town), id:"link-town-data1", remote:true %></button>
<div id="town-data1"></div>
<div>other stuff here blah blah</div>
<button id="button-town-data2"><%= link_two, remote:true, etc %></button>
<div id="town-data2"></div>
```

When a user clicks on the button, I want to load a partial into the corresponding div. But I'm having trouble telling rails which div to load. .

```
// show.js.erb
$('#town-data1').html("<%= j (render 'town_data') %>");
$('#town-data2').html("<%= j (render 'town_data') %>");
```

above is what I currently have, but I really want something that looks like this...

```
$(dynamically_generated_selector).html("<%= j (render 'town_data') %>");
```

I don't want to load the partial into every div. That would make it look weird. I want to be able to select where to load the partial will load dynamically based upon which button is clicked... I tried `$(this).html("<%= j (render 'town_data') %>");` but it didn't work. Maybe I could pass parameters into my controller, and then use the parameters within show.js.erb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the problem is to select which div to render data in... and not what content to be rendered (which you already have figured out).

As your button and the target div have similar ID, you can use it. When any button is clicked, take its id eg. 'button-town-data1', remove the part 'button-' and you will have 'town-data1' which is the id of the target div. Use this to render the data in related div. This way you will be able to associate each div with the clicked button.

I can give you the code but I think it's simle string manipulation, so you can try it out